# Hot do I fix Windows 10 Creators Update desktop icon positioning

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop, dpi, windows-10-v1703

I have found that after installing the Windows 10 Creators update on 2 machines so far, the desktop icon spacing is such that there is a massive gap between icons at the bottom of the desktop and the taskbar.

Here is the spacing pre-upgrade:

[image: Pre-upgrade]

Here is the spacing post-upgrade

[image: Post-upgrade]

Note that those images are exactly the same size and resolution, so you can see that the desktop grid has changed.

Here they are side by side:

[image: Pre-upgrade][image: Post-upgrade]

I have tried things like changing the icon size, but it doesn't help, as I suspect the grid itself has changed meaning that is as low as it will go.

I know it's only a minor thing, but it makes the desktop look a little silly, and turning off align to grid has the potential to look even worse.

I don't think it has anything to do with small taskbar icons, but might be related to double height taskbar, as turning that off, the gap is much reduced.

Does anyone know how to fix this positioning so it goes back to how it was before the install of the creators update?

Comment: Yeah, i have that problem as well, the temporary solution i found was holding Ctrl + Scroll to make the icons i little bigger, but i want a real fix

Comment: I have the same issue, although instead of the gap at the bottom, I lost an entire column on the left side of my screen. Every time I move an icon into that column as soon as I click off the icon it reverts back to it's previous position.

Comment: Please update if you find a solution. It's really annoying.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as hamiheim. My dell 5510 has a 4K display, btw.

Comment: Can't put icons in the top left, bug in the new update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be fixed by changing some registry values.
Go to this location in **regedit** :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
```

You will find keys named **IconSpacing** and **IconVerticalSpacing**.

To solve this problem you need to increes the value of **IconVerticalSpacing**.

(You can also play around with the **IconSpacing** value to increase horizontal gap between icons.)

By default,the values of both **IconSpacing** and **IconVerticalSpacing** is **-1125** in Creators Update and in previous versions too.*

*(In 1366x768 resolution and 100% scaling.)

You need to change the **IconVerticalSpacing** value to **-1200** and then sign out and log in again,and it will be same as previous version.

**Proof :**

[image: IconVerticalSpacing's value is -1200]

**P.S.**

You can also use [Winaero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836) to change the icon spacing with a nice user interface.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Okay ,got it :) @DavidPostill

Comment: Wahoo! It worked when I used WinAero tweaker. Note, for 1280x1024, I had to use a value of 78 rather than 80! Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me 1920x1080